# Acces linked list in main class from another class java

Tags: java, inheritance, linked-list

I have this project of an Online Store. The class OnlineStore is where the main method is, that starts the program. I also have 3 classes, User, Item andPackage, with some inherited classes.

I store all users, items and Packages in linked lists.
I created instances in the class OnlineStore inside the main method but I want to be able to access to them every moment; The class Item sould be able to access this linked list and remove an item that has been sold.

```
public class OnlineStore{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<User> users = new  LinkedList<User>();
    LinkedList<Item> itemsSold =  new  LinkedList<Item>();
    LinkedList<Item> items =  new  LinkedList<Item>(
    LinkedList<Package> packages =  new  LinkedList<Package>();
    }
}

//Then I create some instances of Items Users and call their methods of buying, 
//loging in, etc..

//If a item is buyed:

public class Buyer extends User {
    //ATTRIBUTES
    private String accountNumber;
    private LinkedList<Item> boughtItems;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Buyer(String n, String id, String pass, String a){
        super(n, id, pass);
        accountNumber = a;
    }

    //METHODS
    public void buy(Item i){
        boughtItems.add(i);
        //Here I need to acces the first class and remove from availableItems
        items.remove(i);
    }



}
```

Thanks for your help!
John R.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  Is there something wrong with your code that you need help with?  If so, please make sure to [edit] your question to include any compile or runtime errors you're getting, as well as expected vs actual output.  A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I will update my question.
As you can see in my code I have four "maste" linked lists in the main method.
Imagine that my class users is as follows:
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String identifier;
    private String password;

    public User(String n, String id, String pass){
        name = n;
        identifier = id;
        password = pass;
    }
//setters and getters
}

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I will update my question.
The class Buyer extends the class user. If you see the part in the code "items.remove(i)", this actually doesn't work because it cant access to the linkedlist items because is declared outside this class.
How you thing I should do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class OnlineStore{

    public static LinkedList<User> users = new  LinkedList<User>();
    public static LinkedList<Item> itemsSold =  new  LinkedList<Item>();
    public static LinkedList<Item> items =  new  LinkedList<Item>();
    public static LinkedList<Package> packages =  new  LinkedList<Package>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
```

}

Comment: Ok I tried this and it compiles.
But imagine now I create a Buyer b1 = new Buyer("parameers here") and Item i1 = new Item("parameters here")
And then call the method b1.buy(i1):

public void buy(Item i){
    OnlineStore.items.remove(i);
}

Since I need to remove the item from the static list;

This gives me the error: Exception in thread "Main" java.lang.NullPointerException at onlinestore.Buyer.buy [...] at 
onlinestore.main.

Thanks

Comment: Have you placed any items on your list? Because maybe you\`re trying to remove the element that doesn\`t exist in your list. Personally, I would consider not to place the main method inside OnlineStore class, but in some other main class. In that case, Online Store would be normal class and all LinkedLists wouldn`t have to be static and you can access them via methods.